# Subversion - Do full update on subdirectory after immediates-only checkout

Tags: svn, version-control

Good day,

I am attempting to carry out a sparse checkout of parts of a repo. Basically, let's assume I want to just check out the directory structure for the first level of a repo. I could do:

```
svn co --depth=immediates
```

Now, I would like to go into one of the sub-directories in my local working copy, and update it completely (ie: depth=infinity).

```
svn up --depth=infinity
```

However, this does not download/checkout any files at all. I know that I could just manually do

```
svn co URL-to-path --depth=infinity
```

But this would mean that for each subdirectory, I have to type in the full path to the SVN repo, which will become a pain really fast based on how many directories I have to do this for.

Is there a way to force `svn up` to just ignore the `depth` argument previously used by the `checkout` command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`svn up --depth` only adds one more limit, so it cannot download more

for you case `svn up --set-depth` will likely work